# Filtering JavaScript array of objects by property of an object and removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, filtering

I have an array of objects

```
[
{"title": "video01", "src":"/embed/video1","hero":"hero1"},    
{"title": "video02", "src":"/embed/video2","hero":"hero1"},    
{"title": "video03", "src":"/embed/video3","hero":"hero1"},    
{"title": "video04", "src":"/embed/video4","hero":"hero2"},    
{"title": "video05", "src":"/embed/video5","hero":"hero2"},    
{"title": "video06", "src":"/embed/video6","hero":"hero3"},    
{"title": "video07", "src":"/embed/video7","hero":"hero3"},    
{"title": "video08", "src":"/embed/video8","hero":"hero3"}]
```

I need to return a [hero1, hero2, hero3] what would be the best way of doing that?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hay yes I've done the itearation asigning values to Array and then removing duplicates long and ugly. I was hopping for undescore solution perhaps

Comment: Please post anything, you've tried and describe the difficulties you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing duplicates from an array has already been discussed here : [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

If you have access to `Array.prototype.indexOf`, checking for duplicates is easy (FF, Chrome, Opera and IE >= 9, see [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)) :

```
var heroes = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
    var heroName = myArray[i].hero;
    if (heroes.indexOf(heroName) == -1) {
        heroes.push(heroName);
    }
}
```